# How to detect which View in View Hierarchy handle touch event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging

I have several layers of UIViews and would like to find out which view is handling the touch event. I implemented a tap gesture recognizer on the bottom view, but it doesn't respond. So.. I guess a view on higher hierarchy is hijacking the touch and just consume. I enabled UserInteraction on views on higher rank.

Is there a debugging method of touch event?

Answer (score -1):

Use `touchesBegan:withEvent` `method` to know exactly which part has been touched. By this method you can get the view which is on front.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSLog(@"%@",touch.view);
}
```

when touch began on any view and if it's user interaction is on then it take the array(NSSet) of touches take any object of touch and if you given the tag to that view then you easily identified which view has on the front

Comment: Please explain how that is supposed to tell you what view handles the touch!

Comment: when touch began on any view and if its user interaction is on then it take the touched set which has n on which touch happen and if you give the tag to that view then you easily identified which view has on the front.

Comment: add that to your question since currently *the answer* does not answer the actual question.

Comment: thanks @luk2302 for this think it really help other .

Comment: maybe state a bit clearer how you can get the actual view object. I think the sentence is hard to understand.